# How to check internet accessibility in hotspot (Android)

Tags: android

I know how to check internet connectivity (NetworkInfo::isAvailable, isConnected) but I've got problems with hotspots.
When you're connected to a hotspot but you didn't enter the password, you are connected to the internet (so the regular check will return true), but you can't connect to sites.
I there a way to confirm that I didn't pass the hotspot's password check? maybe ping to some server?

Answer (score 0):

Would checking a HTTP response code work for you?

```
String urlFeed = "your_url.com";
URL url = new URL(urlFeed);
URLConnection urlConnection;
urlConnection = url.openConnection();   
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;   
int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
```

And then check the response code for a negative response?